# How to know environment configuration in Pimcore? Like APP_ENV

Tags: pimcore

What is proper way to know current configuration, on which environment is the application running (dev/staging/production)?

Answer (score 0):

You can learn the current configuration (dev, test, stage, prod, ...) like that:

```
if (Pimcore\Config::getEnvironment()=='prod') {
    ; // something
}
```

Here is a documentation:

- Pimcore: https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/10.3/Development_Documentation/Deployment/Configuration_Environments.html
- Symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/configuration.html#configuration-environments

Answer (score 0):

More ways of working with Symfony environments:

https://lindevs.com/get-environment-name-in-symfony